# Three.js-How to represent objects in WebGL pleasantly?

Tags: three.js, webgl, collada

I am using Three.Js to represent a 3D model of a building. Data is a collada file and I am using collada loader.

I have two main problems:

1-when I rotate the building, some walls are vanished in some views and are appeared again in the other views. There are some walls in the red circles, but they are not rendered in this view {Image (1)}. In the other view, they are represented. .
[image: Image (1)]

2-When I have two close surfaces (like walls and spaces in a building), it renders both surfaces which makes it unpleasant. Wall color is yellow and space color is gray. But I want to show the yellow wall and when I turn off the walls, see the spaces.

[image: Image (2)]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you make a simple Collada example (with just a few walls, not your entire model) to demonstrate the issue? Then post it live.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I could solve the issue by importing and exporting data to Collada format using Blender. There was an issue in the data probably.